# Añadir elementos a array bidimensional, que todavía no se ha creado

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist, línea-de-comandos

¿Método que me permitan añadir elementos a un array bidimensional, si este array se crea cuando el usuario introduce sus dimensiones?
Para añadir el objeto habría que especificar el objeto y su fila y columna.

Soy nuevo en java, lo siento si esta pregunta es muy tonta.

Comment: revisa la clase arraylist. Te quitas el problema de añadir elementos en memoria, puesto que tiene sus propios metodos para añadir, leer y eliminar elementos dentro de ella.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: No se puede añadir elementos a un arreglo que no se ha creado. Simplemente, no hay forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Lo primero, no se puede añadir nada a un objeto que no existe. Ademas según tu explicación, lo lógico es que primero el usuario indique las dimensiones de la matriz. En el momento de recibirlas, creas objeto. Segundo, trata de hacer algo de código a ver si puedes hacerlo solo. Si te atascas, ya puedes preguntar poniendo tu código, demostrando que lo has intentado.

Answer (score 2):

No te disculpes, una pregunta que tenga como fin aprender sobre algo que no se sabe, nunca es tonta.

Ahora bien, deberías revisar algunos conceptos teóricos para hablar más correctamente.

Como han mencionado otros usuarios, no se puede asignar valores a objetos que no se han creado.
Lo que intentas decir es que el objeto no se crea en el momento de definir la variable que hace referencia al mismo, sino que se lee las dimensiones y más tarde los datos.

En Java, se crea objetos con el operador `new`, que devuelve un identificador del objeto creado (`OID`) y se asigna a la variable de turno.

```
Objeto objeto = new Objeto();
```

Aquí se crea un objeto, y su identificador de objeto se asigna a la variable `objeto`.

Ahora bien, mientras no crees el objeto, la variable tendrá el valor `null`, que indica que no hace referencia a ningún objeto, puesto que no se ha creado ningún objeto para referenciarlo.

```
Objeto objeto;          // Aquí la variable objeto contiene el valor null
objeto = new Objeto();  // Aquí se crea un objeto y se asigna su OID a la variable objeto
```

En el caso de los `arrays` unidimensionales (vectores) o multidimensionales (matrices), al crear el vector o matriz de objetos, hay que indicar las dimensiones que va a tener.

```
Objeto[] vector = new Objeto[3];       // Vector con 3 objetos
Objeto[][] matriz = new Objeto[3][3];  // Matriz con 3x3 elementos (cuadrícula)
```

Cabe destacar que aunque se crea el vector y la matriz, todos los elementos son variables que contienen el valor `null`, como es de esperar, puesto que la `JVM` inicia todos los objetos a `null` por defecto (las variables de tipos primitivos se inicializan a: `0x00` para `byte`, `0` para enteros, `0.0` para reales, `false` para booleanos o `'\0'` para `char`).

Además, para acceder a un elemento del array, utilizamos la notación.

```
Objeto[][] matriz = new Objeto[3][3];    // Se crea una matriz de 3x3 celdas
Objeto objeto = matriz[fila][columna];   // Obtenemos un elemento (un OID), que será null inicialmente
matriz[fila][columna] = new Objeto();    // Creamos un objeto para la celda indicada
```

Dicho esto, respondo a tu pregunta.

Imaginemos que tenemos un método que lee datos por consola y los devuelve, y que vamos a crear otro método que haga uso del primero para rellenar la matriz.

```
public class Lector {

    // ...

    public Objeto[][] obtenerMatriz() {

        Objeto[][] matriz;    // matriz contiene el valor null

        Consola consola = new Consola();       // Objeto hipotético que lee datos
        int filas = consola.leerNumero();      // Obtenemos la primera dimensión
        int columnas = consola.leerNumero();   // Obtenemos la segunda dimensión
        matriz = new Objeto[filas][columnas];  // Creamos la matriz

        // Ahora, le damos un valor a cada elemento de la matriz
        // Para ello, leemos un objeto y asignamos su OID a la celda correspondiente
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                matriz[i][j] = Consola.leerObjeto();

        return matriz;
    }
}
```

Entonces, desde cualquier punto del programa, como por ejemplo el punto de entrada `main`, podemos hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
public class EjemploMatriz {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        Lector lector = new Lector();
        Objeto[][] matriz = lector.obtenerMatriz();
    }
}
```